# NuGet as an application update mechanism

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

We are developing a .NET 3.5 application (Windows Forms), which is comprised of 3 main parts.

As part of the deployment process, we'd like to be able to continuously update the components after being installed.

I have been thinking about setting up a NuGet server, and packaging component updates as NuGet packages.

Has anyone done such a thing before? Do you think NuGet fits this job?

Our requirements are:

- Receiving of packaged DLL files (but there may be scenarios of additional files in a package
- Detecting dependency on other components (or component versions)
- Auto detecting new component versions

We are using TeamCity for continuous integration and for building our product, i know it integrates well with NuGet and can directly create/publish NuGet packages.

The question is how well can i integrate NuGet with our application? is there any client NuGet code to consume packages? I am wondering if this can work out.

Comment: Personally i think youre trying to bend nuget in ways it wasnt really intended to go. Technically you probably can use Nuget to do this but there are plenty of other deployment platforms aimed at deploying and maintaining applications which are much better suited to this

Comment: I agree that there are other platforms for doing such a thing. The main thing is that our build environment (TeamCity) already has some functionality to handle this, only leaving the client side to pull for updates. Why would you think this is bending NuGet?

Comment: I think you might want to look at chocolatey in the nuget gallery.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1 and 3) Deploying and receiving data from NuGet using NuGet.Core is possible. Check [NuGet push... to Windows Azure](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2011/09/23/NuGet-push-to-Windows-Azure.aspx) and the [source code](https://hg01.codeplex.com/nuget/file/d99a4bb817fa/src/CommandLine/Commands/UpdateCommand.cs) for NuGet.exe's Update -Self command.

We're also featuring this scenario in our upcoming NuGet book - [Pro NuGet](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430241918).

2) Hosting your own feed is easy, check www.myget.org or use the [NuGet gallery](https://github.com/nuget/nugetgallery)

Comment: I would like to completely skip the command line part, and have it integrated into my own .NET. i assume this is possible.

Comment: Yes, check the code for the command-line and integrate it in your sources.

Answer (score 4):

A bit late to the party but I have developed an open source framework that delivers exactly the requirements asked for.

It's called Sidewinder ([http://sidewinder.codeplex.com](http://sidewinder.codeplex.com/)) - the best way to use it is via it's NuGet packages (http://nuget.org/packages/sidewinder).

Essentially you add a small piece of code at the start of your app and the sidewinder component will check the feed (official or custom) for an update to the packages you need, pull them down and unpack them to a temp folder. It then backs up your app to a zip, launches sidewinder.exe (which will complete installation) and returns control to your app indicating it should terminate as an update is pending. Once your app closes, sidewinder.exe copies the updated content from the temp folder into your application folder and if you include a readme.txt in the nuget package will even shellexec that for you.

Answer (score 2):

I think its possible, I do something similar myself in a project I developed. I don't think its 'bending nuget', insofar as you use a private feed and don't try to push these packages to the public nuget feed. Nuget could handle your dependencies with regards to assembly A needs assembly B to function, but as for the dynamic loading/unloading you would have to look towards something like the Managed Extensibility Framework to auto load new modules.

There is client code for Nuget called Nuget.Core, and it's what's used in the Nuget PowerShell window in Visual Studio to download packages. It could be used to perform the functionality you describe, downloading new packages and putting them in places your app expects.

If you are looking for some examples out there, there are some a google search could find, but one that comes directly to mind is [OctopusDeploy](http://octopusdeploy.com/), which is a app deployment framework built around nuget.